Ms graph TimeOff note/description/comment from api
When a user creates a timeoff in teams, he can leave a comment or note for that timeoff. Sometimes this is very important; for example, there may be a description of the reason for changing the schedule and the working time. But for some reason I can’t find anywhere the opportunity to get this note via API. For example, you can get this note in the shift:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schedule-list-shifts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
draftShift.notes
Is there any solution to this problem?
I looked through the documentation but still couldn't find this timeoff note.
